# How to test the update method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I am struggling with testing the update method in Rails. I am using the standard built in testing framework (`test::unit`) and Rails 3.0.8. I have created a minimum application for testing this now, but I can't get it to work. Here is what I do:

I create a new blank rails application:

```
rails new testapp
```

Create a model called Collection:

```
rails generate model collection name:string
```

Run rake db:migrate:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Create a controller called Collections with an update method:

```
rails generate controller collections update
```

In collection_controller.rb I add this minimum update method:

```
def update
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
  @collection.update_attributes(params[:collection])
end
```

The test fixtures are the defaults (collections.yml):

```
one:
  name: MyString

two:
  name: MyString
```

Then I add this to the collection_controller_test.rb under functional:

```
test "should update collection" do
  put :update, :id => collections(:one), :collection => {:name => 'MyString2'}
  assert_equal "MyString2", collections(:one).name
end
```

When I run the test:

```
rake test:functionals
```

It fails with this message:

```
test_should_update_collection(CollectionsControllerTest) [/Users/atle/Documents/Rails/testapp/test/functional/collections_controller_test.rb:6]:
<"MyString2"> expected but was
<"MyString">.
```

Here are the output from test.log:

```
[1m[36mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  [1m SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
[0m
[1m[35mCollection Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = 980190962 LIMIT 1
Processing by CollectionsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>#<Collection id: 980190962, name: "MyString", created_at: "2011-06-12 13:14:13", updated_at: "2011-06-12 13:14:13">, "collection"=>{"name"=>"MyString2"}}
[1m[36mCollection Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = 980190962 LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35mAREL (0.2ms)[0m  UPDATE "collections" SET "name" = 'MyString2', "updated_at" = '2011-06-12 13:14:13.394135' WHERE "collections"."id" = 980190962
Rendered collections/update.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 4.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

In the log I can see the `UPDATE` statement, but I never see a new `SELECT` statement.

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: +1 for a clearly asked question. Nice to see a new user asking an explicit question with this level of detail. Your problem is definitely stemming from `collections(:one)` in your assertion, which simply reads from the fixture again, instead of the db. Cameron and Teddy both have this correct below. (BTW: Look into `factory_girl` and dump fixtures entirely ASAP. They are convenient for getting started, but a horrible mess later on.)

Comment: So the fixtures and the db are two distinct locations. I assumed the fixtures are read into the db at startup and that collections(:one) read from the db. Thanks for clearing things and I'll look into that factory_girl :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're reloading the fixture data instead of reading from the db. Try something like

```
assert_equal "MyString2", Collection.find(collections(:one)).name
```

You might need to specify the id in the fixture.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.

Comment: Don't use the DB in the test if you don't need to. You don't want to test if the DB works, right?

Answer (score 17):

You can make assertions on the instance variable that is created during the HTTP response:

```
test "should update collection" do
  put :update, :id => collections(:one), :collection => {:name => 'MyString2'}
  assert_equal "MyString2", assigns(:collection).name
end
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked too, but I accepted Camerons answer, since he was first ;) Thank you!

Comment: This is the better answer, since it doesn't use the database.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Collection.find(collections(:one)) is ugly.

Comment: Funny thing.. [this approach is deprecated](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html#deprecation-of-assigns-and-assert_template-in-controller-tests) these days.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite variant of this:

```
test "should update collection" do
  coll = collections(:one)
  put :update, :id => coll, :collection => {:name => "MyString2"}
  assert_equal "MyString2", coll.reload.name
end
```

The `assigns(:collection)` trick doesn't actually guarantee the record was saved. This may not be a problem, or it may be a surprise.

Comment: Use `assigns` if possible. You don't need any database interaction for what you want to test.